MSAL login pop-up is not showing user selection in docker image
I have streamlit application, which runs properly in local with MSAL login. but when try to run same code in docker image. code runs fine but pop-up to select user account is coming blank.
my login.py is below:
def login():
     
    st.image("images/nc_header.png")
    st.title("Welcome to Meeting Summarizer")
    auth_data = Msal.initialize_ui(
                client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                authority=AUTHORITY,
                scopes=[], # Optional
                # Customize (Default values):
                connecting_label="Connecting",
                disconnected_label="Disconnected",
                sign_in_label="Sign in",
                sign_out_label="Sign out"
            )

    if not auth_data:
            st.write("Please authenticate to access Meeting Summarizer")
            st.stop()
    return  auth_data       

# account = auth_data["account"]
# print("account", account)

# name = account["name"]
# print("name", name)


if 'accessToken' not in st.session_state:
    
    authValues=login()
    account = authValues["account"]
    print("account", account)

    name = account["name"]
    print("name", name)
    username = account["username"]
    print("username", username)
    # Getting useful information
    access_token = authValues["accessToken"]
    print("access_token", access_token)
    if account:
        st.session_state.logged_in = True
        # Store the name and access token in session state
        st.session_state.name = name
        st.session_state.access_token = access_token
        st.success("Logged in successfully!")
        print("Session State:", st.session_state)
        sleep(0.5)
    
        st.switch_page("pages/Meeting_Notes.py")

my docker file contains below:
FROM python:3.10.11
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "Login.py", "--server.port=8000", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

when run locally , this is the pop-up is visible:

but when I try to run same code with docker image, showing below blank pop-up:

I am expecting to resolve above issue.
I am new to this , any help will be thankful.
